# Linear operator on a dense subset of $L_p$ which is unbounded when extended to $L_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> Let the linear operator $L:C^{\infty}_0([-1,1]) \rightarrow C(\{0\})$
>   be defined as $f(0)$ (evaluating a function in $C^{\infty}_0([-1,1])$
>   at $0.$
>
> I would like to show that extending this to the space $L^p(-1,1)$
>   makes it unbounded and that $C^{\infty}_0([-1,1])$ is dense in this
>   space.

I think I have found a simple example of a function in $L^p(-1,1)$ that shows that the linear operator is unbounded.

If we let $f(x) = M$ for $x=0$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise, then $f$ has $0$ $L_p$ norm, but $Tf=M$, and so there is no such $\alpha$ such that $|Tf| \le \alpha |f|_p$ for all $f \in L^p(-1,1)$. In particular, this would show that $L$ is not linear right?

The only confusion that I have is that, in this case, $f$ is in the equivalence class of the $0$ function, so it feels like a bit of a fuzzy example. But on the other hand, any member of the equivalence class should be valid as it's representative - so perhaps there are no problems here? **I guess what I would like to know, is whether my example is valid?**

Secondly, I am having difficulty showing that $C^{\infty}_0([-1,1])$ is dense in $L^p(-1,1)$. I know I need to show that for any $f \in L^p(-1,1)$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, I need to be able to find a $u \in C^{\infty}_0([-1,1])$ such that $||f-u||_p < \epsilon$, but I'm not really sure where to start.

I have looked at the Weierstrass approximation theorem, as well as density of other subspaces of $L^p(-1,1)$, but in each case, I seem to run into the same problem of having to prove density of some other space. A good push in the right direction, would be very helpful!

Comment: Hint: Think about a bump function and scale it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members of $L^p[-1,1]$ are equivalence classes of functions, where $f\equiv g$  $\iff f(x)=g(x)$ except on a set of measure $0.$ We can remedy the def'n by saying that if $f\in L^p[-1,1]$ and if $f\equiv g\in C^{\infty}_0,$ then $L(f)=g(0)$, as there can be only one such $g.$

If $1\leq p<\infty$ then the operator $L$ is already unbounded on $S_p=\{[f]_p:f\in C^{\infty}_0[-1,1]\}$, where $[f]_p=\{g\in L^p[-1,1]:g\equiv f\}$, because for any $n\in N$ there exists $f_n\in C^{\infty}_0[-1,1]$ with $f_n(0)=1$ and $\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|\;dx<1/n^p.$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer is enlightening, but I;m embarassed to admit, I am still a bit confused at the example you have given. Am I interpreting the set $S_p$ correctly, as a subset of $L_p$, in which the elements of $S_p$ are the equivalence classes of functions, where an arbitrary representative is in $C^{\infty}$? But then you have defined the elements of $[f]_p$ as equivalence classes of $L_p$ as well? I'm a bit confused. Then how is $\int^{1}_{-1}|f(x)|dx < 1/n^p$..I'm struggling to see how this was derived. Could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks again.

Comment: The elements of [f_p] are not members of L_p nor equivalence classes but they are  often,for convenience, spoken of as members of L_p,  when talking of integration. See next comment.

Comment: Example of a sequence $f_n$. Let $h(x)=\exp (-1/x^2)$ for $x\ne 0$ ;  $h(0)=0.$ Let $D^nh$ be the $n$th derivative of $h$. ($D^0h=h$). If $D^nh(0)=0$ & $D^nh(x)=h(x)p_n(1/x)$ where $p_n$ is a polynomial, then $D^{n+1}h(x)=h(x)p_{n+1}(1/x)$ where $p_{n+1}$ is a polynomial, & $D^{n+1}h(0)=0.$ (Because  $h(x)\to 0$ faster than any $(1/x)^m \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$.) Let  $f_n(x)=1-h(n x).$ For $ r\in (0,1),$ we have $f_n(x)\to 0$ uniformly on $[-1,-r]\cup [r,1],$ and $0\leq f_n(x)<1$ for $x\in [-r,r].$  Hence, as $n\to \infty$ we have    $ L([f_n])\; / \; \|[f_n]\|_p\to \infty.$

Comment: Ahh yes, yes, that makes a lot of sense now. However, I do have one more question just to clarify; $[f_n]$ here is supposed to be an equivalence class of functions right? So shouldn't say $f_1 \equiv f_2$? But this wouldn't be true for your definition of $f_n$? Thanks again.

Comment: For my $f_n$ we have $f_1(x)-f_2(x)=h(x)-h(2 x)\ne 0$ except when $x=0$. So $f_1\not \equiv f_2$.

Comment: One point of my example is that your original operator $L$ on the space of functions $C^{\infty}[-1,1],$ with the $p$-norm, is not bounded on this space.  We can isomorphically identify this space with the vector subspace $\{[f]: f\in C^{\infty}\}$ of  the space $L^p$.  (Some write $L_p,$ some prefer to write $L^p$.)

Comment: I think I am starting to get it. So just to be clear, you are isomorphically identifying $[f_n]$ with $\{[f] : f \in C^{\infty} \}$. Would this be injective, but not surjective? As in $\{[f] : f \in C^{\infty} \}$ would 'contain' more than $[f_n]$? Thanks so much for your patience with me.

Comment: Isomorphically identify any $g\in C^{\infty}$  with $[g]\in L_p$. Then $C^{\infty}$ is identified with a vector subspace of  $L_p$. A proper subspace, and not a closed subspace.